# Binary Search Tree Find minimum not clear

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

### The logic I tried:

```
 def min_tree_value(self):
        
       while self.left:
            self.left = self.left.left
        
        return self.data
```

### Actual Python program Logic:

```
def min_tree_value(self):
        if self.left is None:
            return self.data
        
        return self.left.min_tree_value()
```

The actual Python program logic is in recursion form. I tried the same logic in While loop()

I'm not sure whether my logic is correct. Do help me to figure out the incorrect logic and point where I'm Wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is almost there, but not quite:

```
def min_tree_value(self):
    node = self
    while node.left:
        # don't change the structure by rebinding node.left,
        # but iterate the tree by moving along nodes!
        node = node.left  
    return node.data
```

Note that in the original code, you never reassign `self` before returning its value, so you always returned the root value.

Comment: Thank You !! for your reply... But I Certainly felt the Query raised by me was not correct. So I just edited it. Do check it up... Do correct me over the logic side of my mistake...

Comment: Added a fix for your code that originally eluded me :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the question asks about finding the minimum element in a binary tree.

The algorithm you used, will find the minimum element in the **Binary Search Tree** (as the leftmost element is the minimum).

For finding minimum element in a **simple** Binary Tree, use the following algorithm:

```
# Returns the min value in a binary tree 

def find_min_in_BT(root): 
    if root is None: 
        return float('inf') 
    res = root.data 
    lres = find_min_in_BT(root.leftChild) 
    rres = find_min_in_BT(root.rightChild) 
    if lres < res: 
        res = lres 
    if rres < res: 
        res = rres 
    return res
```

**Additions to the answer after OP changed the question:**

**The logic for the algorithm you tried is correct, with a small correction in the implementation: `self = self.data`. Both of them find the leftmost element.**

**I have also tested both the functions which return the same output:**

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):

        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data


    def insert(self, data):

        if self.data:
            if data < self.data:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            elif data > self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.data = data

    def findval(self, lkpval):
        if lkpval < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                return str(lkpval)+" Not Found"
            return self.left.findval(lkpval)
        elif lkpval > self.data:
            if self.right is None:
                return str(lkpval)+" Not Found"
            return self.right.findval(lkpval)
        else:
            print(str(self.data) + ' is found')

    def PrintTree(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.PrintTree()
        print( self.data),
        if self.right:
            self.right.PrintTree()

    def min_tree_value_original(self):
        if self.left is None:
            return self.data
        return self.left.min_tree_value_original()

    def min_tree_value_custom(self):
        
        while self.left:
            self = self.left
        return self.data 
    
root = Node(12)
root.insert(6)
root.insert(14)
root.insert(3)
root.insert(3)
root.insert(1)
root.insert(0)
root.insert(-1)
root.insert(-2)

print(root.min_tree_value_original())
print(root.min_tree_value_custom())
```

**Output:**

```
-2
-2
```

Here -2 is the smallest and the leftmost element in the BST.

Comment: Thank You !! for your reply... But I Certainly felt the Query raised by me was not correct. So I just edited it. Do check it up... Do correct me over the logic side of my mistake... I want to convert a recursion loop into while loop..